# Python: how to show DeprecationWarnings only when triggered by my code

Tags: python, deprecation-warning

Is there a way to show `DeprecationWarnings` if and only if they are triggered by my code (i.e, if I can actually fix them)?

For example, if the `foo` module is deprecated (and calls `warnings.warn` on import), I would like to see the warning if the import call is in one of "my" files (identified by e.g. its path), but I'd like it to be hidden if my code imports `bar` (also outside of my control), which then imports `foo`.

The `warnings.filterwarnings` function takes a `module` parameter, but as far as I can tell this is matched against the module that generated the warning. I believe what I'm interested in is the module that is one stack frame higher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The `warnings.filterwarnings` function takes a `module` parameter, but as far as I can tell this is matched against the module that generated the warning. I believe what I'm interested in is the module that is one stack frame higher.

That's not quite right. `module` does what you need, *if* the code that issues the warning uses `stacklevel` properly.

DeprecationWarnings are supposed to be shown at the point where the deprecated code was used, not inside the deprecated code itself. To support this, `warnings.warn` provides a `stacklevel` argument, allowing a warning to be issued at a higher level in the call stack than the `warnings.warn` call itself.

Warning filters check the location the `stacklevel` says a warning is associated with, not the location of the `warnings.warn` call. That means that for code that uses `stacklevel` properly, you can use warning filters with the `module` argument to only see DeprecationWarnings associated with your code. If the deprecated code *doesn't* set the correct `stacklevel`... then you're out of luck.

Answer (score 2):

The [`module`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#the-warnings-filter) argument of [`warnings.filterwarnings`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#warnings.filterwarnings) is exactly what you need:

> `module` is a string containing a regular expression that the start of
> the fully qualified module name must match, case-sensitively.

So you can add two warning filters, one with an action of `'default'` and a module regex pattern that matches fully qualified module names for which you want warnings displayed, and another with an action of `'ignore'` and an empty regex pattern that will match everything else (the latter filter takes precedence by default), suppressing warnings for them:

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore', category=DeprecationWarning, module='')
warnings.filterwarnings('default', category=DeprecationWarning,
    module=r'__main__|my_package\.') # replace my_package with your package names

import imp # will produce DeprecationWarning as this is done from __main__
```